# Number of occurrence of a face between an interval of [40 cm; 80cm]

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection

I tried to increase++ a number (i) each time the distance between the camera and my face is between 40 cm and 80 cm. Unfortunately when it happen the textview shows (The number of occurrence is: 50). Help me please

```
public void update(final Messsage msg) {    
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        if (msg.getDistanceToFace() > 40 && msg.getDistanceToFace() < 80) {
            textView.setText("The number of occurrence is: " + i);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably add a `break` after you set the text, the way you coded it will set a text for all the iteration of i but you will only see the last one (50)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to increase the number when the face is a certain length away, shouldn't you do something more on the lines of this?

```
public void update(final Messsage msg) {
    int i = 0;
    if (msg.getDistanceToFace() > 40 && msg.getDistanceToFace() < 80) {
        i++;
        textView.setText("The number of occurrence is: " + i);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Maybe you'll need to have that `i` a global variable or an argument to the function, not sure without having more of the code.

If you don't want the `i` to increase really fast (because it increments each time the `update` function is called and the phone is close to the face), a simple code to do that would be something like

```
public void update(final Messsage msg) {
    boolean isCloseToFace = false;
    int i = 0;
    if (msg.getDistanceToFace() > 40 && msg.getDistanceToFace() < 80) {
        if (!isCloseToFace) {
            i++;
            isCloseToFace = true;
        }
        textView.setText("The number of occurrence is: " + i);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        isCloseToFace = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But It increases without stopping untill the face exits from the interval.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't stop increasing. :(

Comment: if you want it to stop increasing, you would have to do some logic to that end. I'll update my answer with an example of that.